# What's causing my ASP.NET Core application to throw an 'InvalidOperationException' error while implementing paging?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, paging

When i am trying to get load https://localhost:7242/product I am getting following error

I had to implement paging in this page

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__231`3[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[WebApplication3105.Models.Product,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication3105.Models.Category]],WebApplication3105.Models.Category,WebApplication3105.Models.ProductCategory]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'X.PagedList.IPagedList`1[WebApplication3105.Models.ProductCategory]'.

Model classes

```
namespace WebApplication3105.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }

    }
}


namespace WebApplication3105.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public String CategoryName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Product> Product { get; set; }



    }
}



namespace WebApplication3105.Models
{
    public class ProductCategory
    {

       public Product product { get; set; } 

        public Category category { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

Controller code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; 
using PagedList.Mvc;
using WebApplication3105.Data;
using WebApplication3105.Models;
using X.PagedList;

namespace WebApplication3105.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MVCDbContext dbContext;

        public ProductController(MVCDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? page)
        {
            List<Product> products = dbContext.Product.ToList();
            List<Category> categories = dbContext.Category.ToList();
            int recordsPerPage = 2;


            var data = from p in products
                       join c in categories on p.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId into table1
                       from c in table1.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, recordsPerPage)
                       select new ProductCategory
                       {
                           product = p,
                           category = c
                       };
            
            return View(data);
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult AddProduct()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public async Task<IActionResult> AddProduct(Product productRequest)
        {
           

                var product = new Product()
                {
                    ProductName = productRequest.ProductName,
                    CategoryId = productRequest.CategoryId
                };

                await dbContext.Product.AddAsync(product);
                await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
           
        }


    }
}
```

View Page

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
}


@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core;
@using X.PagedList
@model IPagedList<WebApplication3105.Models.ProductCategory>

<h1 class="text-center text-uppercase">
    List of products
</h1>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class="bg-dark text-white">
        <tr>
            <th>Product Id</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Category Id</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var data in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>data.product.ProductId)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>data.product.ProductName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>data.product.CategoryId)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>data.category.CategoryName)</th>     
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>

   <div class="pagedList">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just help you scope the issue and you need to modify the `data` by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**Test Result**

[image]

You should change your code like below:

```
int recordsPerPage = 2;


var data = from p in products
           join c in categories on p.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId into table1
           from c in table1.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, recordsPerPage)
           select new ProductCategory
           {
               product = p,
               category = c
           };

return View(data.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, recordsPerPage));
```

**The reson for the issue**

The data source is wrong, you should change your linq query.